# How pinhole camera works?

Tags: imaging, camera

What is the working principle of pinhole camera? What is the function of translucent screen in the camera? Now, if we look behind the translucent screen, what do we actually see: the image formed on the screen (real one), or any other virtual image? How can we see the image formed on the screen? Do the light pass through the screen and reach my eye or the light from the back gets reflected on the back of the screen and reach my eye forming an image?

Answer (score 3):

Pinhole camera works on the principle of straight path of light.
Now, Each point of the body emits light, and, just like a flashlight, the beam of light from that point passes through the pinhole and creates a point of light on the back wall of the camera . All the points in the scene do that at the same time, so an entire image, in focus, is created on the back wall of the camera.

[image]

But the image created is inverted because, only the inclined rays can pass through the hole i.e the rays from top of the body gradually moves downward and rays from below moves upward forming an inverted image on the wall of the camera.(The rays converge at the hole and then diverge out, forming an inverted image).
Now coming to the real image part, as the image is formed on the screen it is termed as real image. To understand this you have to know the difference between real and virtual image.
A real image is formed on screen, whereas a virtual image seems like to form on screen(but actually doesn't).See the images below...

[image]

Here's a rough diagram you asked for

[image]

Here an inverted T is formed on the the screen, and the screen being translucent part of the light from the image can pass through it and reach eye!!

Comment: But..how my eye see that image, because in pinhole camera translucent screen in in front of our eye , do the rays that are forming image  on screen , pass through that translucent screen , help us to see the img . Or real image formed on screen  and light rays coming from the hole from where we are looking into camera hit that screen and came back to our eye help is to see?

Comment: Yes, the ray passes through the translucent screen,that's why it is used.It serves two functions...1)Providing a surface for image to form.2)Letting some light to pass through it , so that we can observe from the back of the screen and perform suitable adjustments.

Comment: But to form image on screen we need rays from screen diverging so that we can extend it back  and know the point from where it is coming , but here  rays are simply passing through screen but not diverging from  points on screen?

Comment: Check out this 
          https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/666676/313211

Comment: If possible can u show it by a diagram (rough)

Comment: @SureshChandraPal Re: "but here rays are simply passing through screen but not diverging from points on screen"  No, the screen is translucent like the thin white paper [here](https://static.lcipaper.com/img/blog/vellum-paper-array.jpg), so, more important (for seeing the image) than the rays passing through (almost) unperturbed, are the ones making the screen shine with the image (a mechanism that resembles an old tube TV). But more often than not one would actually use photographic paper instead of a translucent screen.

Comment: Thank u so.....much for diagram ....really so sweet of u. But in diagram u draw rays diverging from point on screen where real images are formed ,  but we know rays aren't diverging FROM scren they r already diverging ,coming from object so....how our eye extend these rays back in order to know from where rays are coming

Comment: The thing you are talking about occurs in reflection where we have to trace back the path of the light to see where the image is formed.But here consider the image formed i.e the inverted T as source which is emmiting light.And we are receiving that light directly from the source!