# How our eye see real images formed by pinhole camera?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, vision, camera

How do we(eye) see real image form in pinhole camera?

1.Are rays that are forming image pass through screen and reach our eye help us too see it ?

**OR**

2. Light rays from hole from where we are looking at image , hit screen and form its image in our eye.

Here is a diagram I made
[image]

Which shows correct formation image of real image formed by pin hole camera in our eyes?
I have asked this question once but I haven't describe what actually doubt I am facing.

So now I done it, please don't downvote , I am super confused in this doubt. Please help. You all have better knowledge than me, tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Hi Suresh. Rather than post another question, it’s recommended you edit the [original one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/666668/). Thanks.

Comment: I tried but didn't open

Answer (score 1):

Case 1 is correct. We see the image formed on the screen as the screen allows light to pass through it.

Comment: But....to see things we need diverging rays , so that we can draw it back and find point from where it is coming , here it(rays )  is simply passing how our eye extend it back to see from where it is coming?

Comment: If possible can u show it by a diagram (rough)

Comment: Your second diagram is not correct , as it can also be observed in dark, hence there is no need of any external light to bounce back from the screen so that you can see it!! First diagram is correct....I have added the diagram you asked for in your previous question...check that out!!

Comment: Thank u so  .......much

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/666749/313211                     please check out this one too.